# Pygame Error: Mpeg video will not play

Tags: python, pygame, movie, mpeg

picture block before sequence header block is the error I get when i try to play my mpeg video file in pygame.

i have no idea how to fix this:

```
global movie
movie = pygame.movie.Movie("movie.mpeg")
if movie.has_video():
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(movie.get_size())
    movie_length = movie.get_length()
    movie.set_volume(0.99)
    movie.set_display(screen)
    movie.play()
```

This is all I have to play the movie. I believe this should play. Though the 
"picture block before sequence header block" error pops up.

What is wrong?

Comment: I took your code, threw in an `import pygame` and `pygame.init()` at the top, and it ran fine. My research tells me that the error you are getting is from SDL, not pygame. It is possible that the problem is the movie you are using. Can you try using a different movie to test your code?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the video using ffmpeg.

To install ffmpeg follow this youtube video and link mentioned in it.

**[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lSb-jLEJ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3lSb-jLEJJM)**JM

After installation convert the video using this command:-

**ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -target ntsc-vcd -vcodec mpeg1video -an output.mpg**

Answer (score 0):

I had this error myself, and I fixed it using **ffmpeg** and converting my .mpg video with this command:<sup>*</sup>

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -target ntsc-vcd -vcodec mpeg1video -an output.mpg
```

<sup>*</sup> This answer was found on the [Linux Distro Community forum](https://bbs.linuxdistrocommunity.com/discussion/2081/ffmpeg-convert-mpeg).